# It shouldn't be possible to improve a suggested edit without changing anything

Tags: bug, review, edits, suggested-edits

I encountered a bug while reviewing Suggested Edits. I clicked Improve to improve the edit and then I accidentally clicked Save Edits before I changed anything. To my surprise, I got no error message and Community♦ approved the edit and it said that I edited it (although I didn't make any changes, I just clicked the Save Edits button):

[image]

However, since I didn't make any actual edit, it's not visible that I made an empty edit, it only says that the user who suggested the edit edited the post:

[image]

I also tested to see if it did the same thing with Reject and Edit, so I tried to review a bad suggested edit as Reject and Edit and then click Save Edits without changing anything. That worked as it should, so I got an error message when trying to submit the empty edit:

[image]

I think that it would be good if such an error message also shows up when a user tries to submit an empty edit after clicking Improve.